# How to programmatically refresh an Eclipse view, or RSE file subsystem?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rse

How can I programmatically update an Eclipse view? (I suppose this might not need to be specific to RSE?).

Background: I use [Remote System Explorer (RSE)](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) for Eclipse, do some stuff by executing remote commands via SSH, which creates new files on the remote host. I realized that the SFTP file listing in the Remote systems view does not automatically get updated to show the newly created file.

I have managed so far to get the relevant view, like so:

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IViewRegistry viewReg = workbench.getViewRegistry();
IViewDescriptor[] views = viewReg.getViews();
for (IViewDescriptor view : views) {
  String viewID = view.getId();
    System.out.println("View ID: " + viewID);
    if (viewID.equals("org.eclipse.rse.ui.view.systemView")) {
      // Do something with the view here
    }
}
```

... and for possibly doing something RSE specific,  I tried grabbing the RemoteFileSubSystem:

```
IRemoteFileSubSystem rfss = RemoteFileUtility.getFileSubSystem(HPCUtils.getApplication().getHPCHost());
```

... but neither in the ViewDescriptor object, nor the FileSubSystem, I have found any way to refresh the view, or the file subsystem. What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to refresh a container that you constructed?  IOW, a class that you wrote that extends `org.eclipse.rse.core.subsystems.AbstractResource`?

If so, try this code ...

```
ISystemRegistry registry = SystemStartHere.getSystemRegistry();

SystemResourceChangeEvent event = new SystemResourceChangeEvent(this, 
    ISystemResourceChangeEvents.EVENT_REFRESH, yoursubsystem);

registry.fireEvent(event);
```

If you're NOT inside your own resource container, but you know the resource container's object, replace `this` in the `SystemResourceChangeEvent` construction with the object.

Comment: Indeed, this does the trick, if i send in my "rfss" object above, as the "yoursubsystem" parameter, and switch ISystemResourceChangeEvents.EVENT_REFRESH to ISystemResourceChangeEvents.EVENT_REFRESH_SELECTED_PARENT (only little problem is that this event (EVENT_REFRESH_SELECTED_PARENT) is deprecatted :/ ... any hints on how to get around it?

Comment: The [javadoc's](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.rse.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/rse/core/events/ISystemResourceChangeEvents.html#EVENT_REFRESH_SELECTED_PARENT) indicate 'obtain the selection yourself and do EVENT_REFRESH or EVENT_REFRESH_REMOTE'.  My code uses the EVENT_REFRESH event without a problem.

Comment: Right, thanks. Well, I guess the problem is that I typically has a file in the current directory selected, while I need to refresh it's parent folder in order to see new files. Using EVENT_REFRESH_SELECTED_PARENT had been convenient, since I'd not need to grab the currently selected file, which I need to do now, in order to then get it's parent folder...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with RSE but AFAIK it uses a virtual filesystem. That means refreshing can be done via the normal Resource-API, something like:

```
IFolder folder = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFolder(new Path("path/to/theparent/folder/on/remote/system"));
        folder.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());
```

The Filesystem manager of Eclipse will check your EFS-specific implementation of `org.eclipse.core.filesystem.IFileInfo` for a changed modification date. Make sure that your virtual filesystem will return correct File-Information

Comment: Strange ... I don't seem to have any ResourcesPlugin (there's nothing to import, with that name :-o).

Comment: You have to add a dependecy to org.eclipse.core.resources. This bundle holds the abstraction-layer for resources. But this works only if you use the EFS integration, see this blog-posting -> http://tmober.blogspot.com/2007/04/target-management-m6-efs-and-webinar.html