# How to programmatically call the `Refresh` functionality on a node in Custom Navigator?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

This is related to a tool(**Software AG Web Designer**) which has added functionalities on top of Eclipse IDE as plugins.

As seen below, the custom navigator is called `Package Navigator`.
Also seen is the `Refresh` button selected on the top node(`Default` name in this case).

Is there a way to programmatically call the `Refresh` functionality from a custom plugin which I am working on?

[image]

---

## Update

All I am able to find is the below-

[image]

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            adaptable="false"
            id="com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator.actions.refresh"
            objectClass="com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator.model.ISLazyTreeParent">
         <action
               class="com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator.actions.RefreshFromServerAction"
               definitionId="org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh"
               enablesFor="1"
               helpContextId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
               icon="icons/tree/refresh.gif"
               id="com.softwareag.is.ui.navigator.actions.refresh"
               label="%refresh_label"
               menubarPath="group.edit"
               tooltip="%refresh_tooltip">
          </action>
          <enablement>
            <or>
                <test property="com.softwareag.is.navigator.property.vcsEnabled"
                    value="true" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
                <test property="com.softwareag.is.navigator.property.vcsNotEnabled"
                    value="true" forcePluginActivation="true"/>
            </or>
          </enablement>
      </objectContribution>
```

And the class is `RefreshFromServerAction`-

```
public class RefreshFromServerAction extends Action implements IActionDelegate {
    private IStructuredSelection selection;

    public RefreshFromServerAction() {
        this.selection = StructuredSelection.EMPTY;
        this.setId(ActionFactory.REFRESH.getId());
        this.setActionDefinitionId("org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh");
    }

    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection sel) {
        if (sel instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            this.selection = (IStructuredSelection) sel;
        } else {
            this.selection = StructuredSelection.EMPTY;
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        this.run((IAction) null);
    }

    public void run(IAction action) {
        ISServerNode[] servers = AssetUtils.getSelectedServersFromSelection(this.selection);
        if (servers != null) {
            NavigatorHelper.getInstance().setExpandAllPath((ISServerObjectBase) null, (ISServerNode) null);
            List<ISServerNode> refreshedServers = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 0; i < servers.length; ++i) {
                if (!refreshedServers.contains(servers[i])) {
                    ServerConnection serverConnection = servers[i].getServerConnection();
                    if (serverConnection != null && !serverConnection.isConnected()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    ISTreeParent[] selectedAssetsFromSelection = AssetUtils
                            .getSelectedAssetsFromSelection(this.selection);
                    ISTreeParent[] var7 = selectedAssetsFromSelection;
                    int var8 = selectedAssetsFromSelection.length;

                    for (int var9 = 0; var9 < var8; ++var9) {
                        ISTreeParent isTreeParent = var7[var9];
                        ServerElementsCache.getInstance().clearCache(serverConnection, isTreeParent);
                    }

                    if ((new ISAssetSaver()).askAndSaveDirtyEditors(servers[i].getServerConnection())) {
                        ISNavigatorPlugin.getDefault().notifyListeners(new NavigatorEvent(5, servers[i], this));
                        refreshedServers.add(servers[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Do you need to create its object first and then do the needful. Or is there any standard way to call the command?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040628/4889267

Comment: You need to know what that menu item is bound to. Use plug-in spy to find out what action/command it uses.

Comment: @greg-449: Will check and update shortly.

Comment: @greg-449: Can you please suggest on the updated part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action appears to be implementing a handler for the `org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh` command. So you should be able to use the `IHandlerService` to execute that command.

You will need to call the handler service for that view since other views / editors will have different handlers for this command.

```
IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("view id"); 

IHandlerService handlerService = view.getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand("org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh", null);
```

Comment: Flawless. It's able to refresh. I also want to expand the nodes of the tree (nodes are called packages in the Default parent node in the Package Navigator, refer to the above image). Any suggestions?